# Syntax of call to super class constructor

Tags: matlab

Within a subclass constructor, what is the difference between calling `obj@SuperClass(a,b);` and `obj = obj@SuperClass(a,b);`

Both are found in doc, for ex. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html)

Comment: I don't think it overwrites anything, since with multiple inheritance calling `obj@parentClass1() ; obj@parentClass2() ;` works flawlessly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical syntax for calling a superclass constructor is

```
obj = obj@SuperClass(args)
```

(see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html#bsa1tzj)).

This is comparable to calling any constructor, where the output of the function call is assigned to a variable:

```
obj = SuperClass(args)
```

However, because the superclass constructor must initialize fields inside a (larger) derived object, the `obj` to be modified must be passed in some way to the function call, hence the (awkward) `obj@` syntax.

But because we pass the object to be initialized, which is modified, we don’t really need to capture that output any more. Hence the other form,

```
obj@SuperClass(args)
```

does exactly the same things in all situations I have encountered.

There is no difference that I can see. I would be surprised if the first syntax did any data copying whatsoever, that has most certainly been optimized out, just like `obj = obj.method(args)` doesn’t copy the object.

Comment: `obj = obj.method(args)` does copy the object (or at least the changed portions of it) if it's a non-handle object and `method`changes any of the properties on `obj`! (Might be optimizable away in the case where there are no other object references to the value in obj, and no try/catch frame on the stack.) This is actually important because it gives you atomic mutating methods. Same copy-on-write behavior as modifying a struct or other Matlab array. The "don't need to capture superclass ctor return" seems to be a special case only for constructors.

Comment: Also check out the more-specific doco on calling superclass constructors: looks like `obj@superclass(args)`, without the `obj = ...` is the canonical form for superclass ctor calls. (This was news to me!) https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brd2m9e-6

Comment: @AndrewJanke That's the page linked by OP. In there indeed they indicate you don't need the assignment, but there's one piece of code on that page where they do use the assignment. // `obj = obj.method(args)` semantically copies the object, but the copy is optimized out. This is true for any function defined as `function a = name(args, a, more_args)`, if the caller also uses the same variable in the two places for `a`. See [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/).

Comment: Oops; didn't notice that was the same page. // In my testing, the Matlab in-place optimization does not work on data held inside the fields of structs or objects (at least as of R2019b), even if you otherwise hold to the conditions they describe there. AFAICT, objects don't get to benefit from in-place optimization, except on local variables inside their methods.